# Is there a way to predict the difference between two primes based on previous differences

Tags: prime-numbers

If we know the difference between for instance 
$5-3=2$ and if we also know the difference between 
$7-5=2$, can we then predict the difference between 
$X-7=$? Where $X = 11$.

Is there an equation/algorithm that can predict the difference without knowing $X$? Based on sums or something?

Comment: not really but we can prove that say 5 consecutive differences can't all be the same ( unless they are 5 ( impossible in the odd primes)), in any 5 values at least 2 must share their remainders when dividing by 5. this is a straight application of the pigeonhole principle to primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: If the Twin Prime Conjecture http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimeConjecture.html   is false, then we can say there is a number M so that $p_{i+1}-p_i$>2 , where $p_i$ is the $i_th$ prime.

Comment: For any sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ of which $a_1$ is known, knowing the sequence of differences $a_2-a_1,\ a_3-a_2,\ a_4-a_3,\cdots$ is exactly the same thing as knowing the sequence itself.

Comment: we know all primes greater than 3 are 1 or 5 remainder on division by 6 ...